# Other controller is not triggered when a route with the asterisk template exists {*url} in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application where I configured a so called "default" controller that handles all requests. Controller name is `FrontController` and it has the only action called `Index`. 
It is configures in the following way:

```
routes.MapAreaRoute(
    name: "Front",
    areaName: "Front",
    template: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Front", action = "Index" }
);
```

All requests go through this controller.
I need to configure custom error pages that would handle internal server errors and for that purpose I have created an `ErrorController` that should handle the request. `ErrorController` has a single action called `Error`. The route is configured in the following way before the default front route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "error",
    template: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { },
    constraints: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" }
);
```

and error handling is enabled in Startup using ``:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error", "?statusCode={0}");
```

**The problem** is that the error controller is not triggered when front route is defined, even though the error route is defined before the front route.

Comment: You specify the route template to be `{controller}/{action}` with `controller = "Error", action = "Error"`. So the route is `/Error/Error`, not `/error`.

Comment: Thank you @poke. I took this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your route has the template `{controller}/{action}` with constraints `Error` for both parts which means there *must* be a controller and an action in the request URL with the name Error. Your error definition says to go to `/error`, which does not have an action. Therefore this route doesn’t match.

Define the template as just `error` and define the defaults to point to `ErrorController` and the action as whatever you want and then that will be called only when a request is done to the URL `/error`, everything else will go through to your wildcard.